# requests.session - how do I know I'm using persistant connection

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm using sessions from requests.

```
 self.session = requests.Session()
```

The program is working but how do I check I'm using one session to send the requests and not just recreating requests at every call successfully.
Want to make sure using a persistant connection with keep-alive

Comment: "session" does not mean "persistent connection".

Answer (score 0):

When you make a session instance with requests and use that session instance to make consecutive requests, then you are definetly using the same session object.

```
s = requests.Session()  #<-- created session object
r = s.get(url1)         #<-- using the same session instance
r = s.get(url2)         #<-- using the same session instance
b = s.get(url3)         #<-- using the same saession instance


r = requests.get(url4)  #<-- using a new request, NOT the same session
```

Comment: Is there a way I can check by debug or something to verify it is using the same session instance. What will happen if I send a session request after ten minutes ? Does it create a new session

Comment: I am not an expert with requests but one thing should be certain, if you are using the same session instance, then you definitely must be using the same session, and as far as I know requests keeps the session alive by default unless you specify otherwise, some body correct me if I am wrong

Comment: when you instantiate a request session, you are effectively using an instance, and when you use that same instance to make multiple requests then you are using just one instance